# composer update removes previously installed packages from symfony flex

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony4

When i install some libs to my symfony 4.3 project with flex:

```
composer require twig monolog
```

Outputs:

```
Using version ^1.0 for symfony/twig-pack
Using version ^3.4 for symfony/monolog-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing twig/extra-bundle (v2.12.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-pack (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.25.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bridge (v4.3.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.4.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Symfony operations: 2 recipes (9554635a5313eba1c8b1d73eafba51c3)
  - Configuring twig/extra-bundle (>=v2.12.1): From auto-generated recipe
  - Configuring symfony/monolog-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
Executing script cache:clear
```

They are added to symfony.lock but not to composer.json.

So when i next run

```
composer update
```

The libraries are removed and unconfigured again.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 5 removals
  - Removing twig/extra-bundle (v2.12.1)
  - Removing symfony/twig-pack (v1.0.0)
  - Removing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.4.0)
  - Removing symfony/monolog-bridge (v4.3.5)
  - Removing monolog/monolog (1.25.1)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Symfony operations: 2 recipes (0637fcde6e70b4f7a32f5fed62f0c462)
  - Unconfiguring twig/extra-bundle (>=v2.12.1): From auto-generated recipe
  - Unconfiguring symfony/monolog-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
Executing script cache:clear
```

Is this normal behaviour?
Seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: I made a fresh skeleton project and executed your require command.  Things work as expected.  monolog-bundle 3.4 and twig-pack 1.0 were added to composer.json.  Running composer update did not change anything.  What php version are you using?  And did your composer.json come from a legacy project or was it newly created?  Consider creating a fresh project and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: its from a almost fresh project with already some more deps. i recently added     `"minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true, `

Comment: Okay.  My composer debug knowledge is pretty much limited to starting over and trying to figure out where things went wrong.  I do know that there is a [new Twig 3.0](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-twig-namespaced-classes) being worked on.  It's possible that the dev stability is messing things up.

Comment: yes, just tested on fresh symfony project with `minimum-stability": "dev", "prefer-stable": true` but seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because there was an error in the project during the following `cache:clear` in composer update.

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

Then composer or flex starts a rollback and the composer.json is not updated, the symfony.lock however remains updated.